# recursive Instantiating of objects- hydra

Tags: python, fb-hydra, albumentations

I'm trying to instantiate a composition of transformers.
In native *Python* this looks like this:

```
import albumentations as A
transforms = A.Compose([
   A.Rotate(limit=10), 
    A.ToGray(p=1),
])
print(transforms)
```

output:

```
Compose([
  Rotate(always_apply=False, p=0.5, limit=(-10, 10), interpolation=1, border_mode=4, value=None, mask_value=None),
  ToGray(always_apply=False, p=1),
], p=1.0, bbox_params=None, keypoint_params=None, additional_targets={})
```

I'm trying to instantiate the same transformation with *Hydra*, but for some reason, the recursive instantiation is failed and only the list of transforms is instantiated but not the outer (`A.Compose`) function.

```
from omegaconf import OmegaConf
import hydra
conf = OmegaConf.create({"compose": {"_traget_": "albumentations.Compose", "_recursive_": True, "transforms": [{"_target_": "albumentations.Rotate", "limit": 10}, {"_target_": "albumentations.ToGray", "p": 1}]}})
print(OmegaConf.to_yaml(conf))
```

output:

```
compose:
  _traget_: albumentations.Compose
  _recursive_: true
  transforms:
  - _target_: albumentations.Rotate
    limit: 10
  - _target_: albumentations.ToGray
    p: 1
```

But instantiation is failed:

```
print(hydra.utils.instantiate(conf.compose))
```

output:

```
{'_traget_': 'albumentations.Compose', 'transforms': [Rotate(always_apply=False, p=0.5, limit=(-10, 10), interpolation=1, border_mode=4, value=None, mask_value=None), ToGray(always_apply=False, p=1)]}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. This code does not run on Hydra 1.1 and results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 30, in <module>
    print(hydra.utils.instantiate(conf.compose))
  File "/home/omry/dev/hydra/hydra/utils.py", line 95, in instantiate
    target = _get_target_type(config, kwargs)
  File "/home/omry/dev/hydra/hydra/_internal/utils.py", line 640, in _get_target_type
    raise InstantiationException("Unable to determine target")
```

The reason is that your first node does not have a `_target_` field, instead it has a `_traget_`.
Once you correct this, it works fine.